# How to modify XML with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify a status flag in an XML structure using Javascript. Using examples found on the internet I believe this should work:

```
test = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no' ?>" + 
    "<resultaat>" +
        "<type>6</type>" +
        "<status>I</status>" +
        "<start_datum>2012-06-16 00:00:00</start_datum>" +
        "<eind_datum></eind_datum>" +
    "</resultaat>"
```

To change the content of the status field:

```
$(test).find("status").text("D")
```

The result is however that test is not modified and still contains the old status `I`

**Thanks for the answers**

The correct insight is that you need to convert to an XMLObject first and modify this.

Below is how I ended up doing it:

```
/* Convert Text to XML Object */
doc = $.parseXML(test)

/* Change the fields required */
$(doc).find('status').text('D')

/* Back to Text */
str = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc);
```

Comment: That's because `test` is a string and you're not modifying it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
<p id="someElement"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>

var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );

/* append "RSS Title" to #someElement */
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );

/* change the title to "XML Title" */
$title.text( "XML Title" );

/* append "XML Title" to #anotherElement */
$( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I ended up doing it like this: 


/* Convert to XML Object */
doc = $.parseXML(test)

/* Modify Content */
$(doc).find('status').text('D')

/* Back to Text */
str = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc);

Answer (score 0):

you need to write code something like this...

```
test = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no' ?>" + 
    "<resultaat>" +
        "<type>6</type>" +
        "<status>I</status>" +
        "<start_datum>2012-06-16 00:00:00</start_datum>" +
        "<eind_datum></eind_datum>" +
    "</resultaat>";

def = $(test).find("status").text("D");

console.log(def);
```

To make it work....

Comment: That just gives you `<status>`.

Comment: if you carefully see the status variable in console it have <status> as a "D" so its actually changed.

Comment: That's not the point; the OP wants the entire XML back, not just the one node.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmm, this answers works... but not allways. I'm using an old webkit version wich is bundled inside Tidesdk and i have some weird problems:

```
$(xml).find("whatever").append("<however></however>");
// doesn't modify xml

$("<however></however>").appendTo($(xml).find("whatever"));
// does modify xml
```

??? :_)